# Set window.top from iframe location href - cross domain

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a such problem: 
I have to load and attachment to iframe like this:

```html
<html>
  <body>
       <iframe class="doc_place" src="../showAttachment.htm?id=${attachment.id}" >
    </iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

But attachment (pdf) can have links to other websites, eg. to www.google.com . Problem is when sb will click on this link, google will be loaded inside "doc_place" frame.
I cannot get  iframe.contentWindow.location.href because of cross domain issue, but I can detect via exception that this links is from other domain and what I want is to make window.top to display the site opened in iframe than. How can I "rewrite" / refresh content of window.top with content of iframe ?

Answer (score 0):

Using `target="_parent"`:

`<a target="_parent" href="yourURL"></a>`

**UPDATE:**

I misunderstood the question, if you have control over the HTML that has the iFrame you can:

`<iframe sandbox="allow-top-navigation">`

and hope that the links in the `pdf` are directed to the top.

Resource: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp

Comment: But  when inside iframe is pdf I cannot access "a" elements.

Comment: @TomekŁoś Could you elaborate or share a link? It still may be possible to create an `<a>` element with javascript.

Comment: suppose We load to iframe pdf from: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ae78zyix8oee992/Document_wp.pdf?dl=0
There we have only link to www.wp.pl portal. When I open such page eg in IE9 with adobe reader, I have no access to iframe content, to change links. Also when sb clicks www.wp.pl I cannot determine outside the clicked links address, to make it window.top

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of help, I don't know much about loading `.pdf` files.